# Wrong price on product page in another currency

Tags: prestashop, currency

i have a problem with price of my product. I use 2 currencies, CZK and EURO.
CZK is working fine, but when i switch to EURO i have a problem with displaying correct price of the product.
Strange is, that after i put product into the cart, the price is correct.

You can see on screenshot 1, that showing price is different than what is in HTML code in tag "content", which is correct value.

On second screenshot u can see shopping cart and correct price.

Even in backoffice, price is correct. Just on product page is rendered wrong.

I find out, its only doing for products with combinations.

And with products with combinations, when i reload page with CTRL+F5, real price will flash there for a second and after rendering of page is complete, it will start showing wrong price.

btw. "MY CONVERSION RATE IS CORRECT"

```
<div>
                            <p class="our_price_display" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">

                                {strip}
                                {if $product->quantity > 0}<link itemprop="availability" href="https://schema.org/InStock"/>{/if}
                                {if $priceDisplay >= 0 && $priceDisplay <= 2}
                                    <span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="{$productPrice}">{convertPrice price=$productPrice|floatval}</span>
                                    {if $tax_enabled  && ((isset($display_tax_label) && $display_tax_label == 1) || !isset($display_tax_label))}
                                        {if $priceDisplay == 1} {l s='tax excl.'}{else} {l s='tax incl.'}{/if}
                                    {/if}
                                    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="{$currency->iso_code}" />
                                    {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="price"}
                                {/if}
                            {/strip}
                        </p>
                            <p id="reduction_percent" {if $productPriceWithoutReduction <= 0 || !$product->specificPrice || $product->specificPrice.reduction_type != 'percentage'} style="display:none;"{/if}>{strip}
                                <span id="reduction_percent_display">
                                    {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'percentage'}-{$product->specificPrice.reduction*100}%{/if}
                                </span>
                            {/strip}</p>
                            <p id="reduction_amount" {if $productPriceWithoutReduction <= 0 || !$product->specificPrice || $product->specificPrice.reduction_type != 'amount' || $product->specificPrice.reduction|floatval ==0} style="display:none"{/if}>{strip}
                                <span id="reduction_amount_display">
                                {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'amount' && $product->specificPrice.reduction|floatval !=0}
                                    -{convertPrice price=$productPriceWithoutReduction|floatval-$productPrice|floatval}
                                {/if}
                                </span>
                            {/strip}</p>
                            <p id="old_price"{if (!$product->specificPrice || !$product->specificPrice.reduction)} class="hidden"{/if}>{strip}
                                {if $priceDisplay >= 0 && $priceDisplay <= 2}
                                    {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="old_price"}
                                    <span id="old_price_display"><span class="price">{if $productPriceWithoutReduction > $productPrice}{convertPrice price=$productPriceWithoutReduction|floatval}{/if}</span>{if $productPriceWithoutReduction > $productPrice && $tax_enabled && $display_tax_label == 1} {if $priceDisplay == 1}{l s='tax excl.'}{else}{l s='tax incl.'}{/if}{/if}</span>
                                {/if}
                            {/strip}</p>
                            {if $priceDisplay == 2}
                                <br />
                                <span id="pretaxe_price">{strip}
                                    <span id="pretaxe_price_display">{convertPrice price=$product->getPrice(false, $smarty.const.NULL)}</span> {l s='tax excl.'}
                                {/strip}</span>
                            {/if}
                        </div>
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: WHEN I DISABLE JS FOR BROWSER, PRICE IS CORRECT

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wss0j.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmxPC.png)

Comment: We need more information. For example, include the part of the code from the theme that displays the price.

Comment: version is 1.6.1.6. and i added part of code from product.tpl where is code to display price